# Can we use JSX in our LWC component with react application?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx, react

I want to build a chatting application in React and I want to use that functionality into my one of the component.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use JSX in an LWC component. You can however, develop an application in react that is completely independent from LWC to achieve your needs and/or use that developed application within an lwc, given that you upload it as a static resource and load it in your LWC. However, you wont be able to use JSX from within your lwc component, as stated before.

Comment: So how to use react library or application so that I can use that application as a component in our LWC.

Comment: `upload your app as a static resource and load it in your LWC` ?